# Reading snapshot of other user in nested firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to loop through my database that is structured like this:
[Realtime Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syvk6.png)

I want to use the RBUserID (RB: Referred By) key which references another user. I'm using the code below to cycle through the UserIDs and find which userID matches the RBUserID.

```
function readOnceandFindRef() {
  refRead.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      var RBUserID = childData.RBUserID;
      console.log(RBUserID);
      debugger; // 1
      refRead.child(RBUserID).once("value", function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log(snapshot.key);
          debugger; // 2
        }
        debugger; // 3
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The forEach loop reads the users and console.log(RBUserID) works, but then it skips through

```
refRead.child(RBUserID).once("value", function (snapshot) {
```

and doesn't runs Debugger 2 and Debugger 3 until after the forEach loop has ended. The chrome debugger shows this:
[Chrome Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc4LE.png)

Any help of why it's skipping the read function inside would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Doug rightly pointed out in his answer, since `once()` is an asynchronous operation, you might need to tweak your function `readOnceandFindRef` for checking all values synchronously.

One of the solution would be using `for-of` loop instead of `forEach` loop.

```
async function readOnceandFindRef() {
  const snapshots = await refRead.once("value");
  for (const snapshot of snapshots) {
    var childKey = snapshot.key;
    var childData = snapshot.val();

    var RBUserID = childData.RBUserID;
    console.log(RBUserID);
    debugger; // 1
    const childSnapshot = await refRead.child(RBUserID).once("value");
    if(childSnapshot.exists()){
      console.log(snapshot.key);
      debugger; // 2
    }
    debugger; // 3
  }
}
```

However, in this case, you will be checking through each user-id one after another.
But using the solution of `Promise.all`, you can execute all such asynchronous operations in parallel.

**Solution 2**

```
async function readOnceandFindRef() {
  const snapshots = await refRead.once("value");
  
  // Following part allows us to execute all the asynchronous operations 
  // at once and still store their outcomes synchronously in the results array.
  const results = await Promise.all(snapshots.map(snapshot => {
    var childKey = snapshot.key;
      var childData = snapshot.val();
  
      var RBUserID = childData.RBUserID;
      console.log(RBUserID);
      debugger; // 1
      return refRead.child(RBUserID).once("value").then(snapshot => {
        const doesRefReadExist = false;
        if(childSnapshot.exists()){
          console.log(snapshot.key);
          doesRefReadExist = true;
        }
        return { rbUserID: RBUserID, doesRefReadExist}
      }) ;
  }))
}
```

The `results` array would look something like:

```
[
  {
     rbUserID: RBUserID-1,
     doesRefReadExist: true/false
  },
  {
     rbUserID: RBUserID-2,
     doesRefReadExist: true/false
  },
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `once()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.   The callback you pass to it is invoked some time later, while the code immediately after it continues to execute.

Note that `once()` also returns a promise that resolves with the snapshot object, and it's more common to use that instead of the callback argument in order to make it easier to do asynchronous programming.